# Skype can not find libssl.so.10 on 64-bit Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, 64-bit, fedora, skype

Skype will not start:

```
$ skype &
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
$ ldd /usr/bin/skype |grep ssl
libssl.so.10 => not found
```

OK, missing libssl. Where is it?

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libssl.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  ... /usr/lib/libsssl.so -> libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  ... /usr/lib/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  ... /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.1e
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  ... /usr/lib/libssl.so.6 -> /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
```

OK, it points to libssl.so.6 which in turns points to the 64-bit version.

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libssl.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  ... /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  ... /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  ... /usr/lib64/libssl.so.6 -> /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
```

So, why is my linkchain not picked up by Skype? (Identical problem exists with libcrypto, BTW).

Comment: [Check this](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=99982) out. Somebody had a similar problem when installing utorrent. It is because you are trying to install 32bit skype on 64bit fedora. In ubuntu and arch, for example, you have to install some packages in order to run 32bit on 64. In fedora I am not sure, because I have never used it.

Comment: I've already been to that page and looked at the suggestions. My symlinks are in order, as far as I can tell. I've installed every single dependency listed on that page (and a few like similar pages). I've read about a dozen pages on "how to install Skype" and of course googled my error messages. Nothing has helped so far.

Comment: 'libssl.so.10: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64' is the important error message here.  You apparently need the 32-bit library.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely wrong for `/usr/lib/libssl.so.6` to point to `/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10` which is why you have problem. The link in `/usr/lib` needs to point to a 32 bit library, so you should see something like this:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libssl.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Oct 31 18:07 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 402K Oct 29 16:16 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.1e*
```

and:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libssl.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Oct 31 18:07 /usr/lib64/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.1e*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Oct 31 18:07 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 429K Oct 29 16:16 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e*
```

It's also wrong for `libssl.so.6` to point to `libssl.so.10` in either directory, as that is basically asserting that two libraries with different SONAMEs are compatible. I'm guessing you added that manually to try and make some other software work?

Comment: I have not installed anything using any other tool but yum. Unfortunately I have not had the time to investigate this further since my last comment above.